# Ext js: Radiogroup in widgetcolumn

Tags: extjs, radio-button, widget

In an `Ext.grid.panel` I load a list of contents as rows with several columns. I would like the user to be able to select only one of these rows via a checkbox/radiogroup column, which has the ID of the respective entry as value. 
I have already discovered the radiobuttons via the xtype `widgtecolumn`. But how can I set this column so that only one radiobutton in this column can be activated?
The current code for the radio column is the following:

```
{
        xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
        bind: {
            text: 'Select topic'
        },
        dataIndex: 'defaultTopic',
        widget: {
            xtype: 'radio',
            simpleValue: true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the user can select only one radiobutton, you have to add the `name` property to your radio widget.

If you were using radiogroups [like in this example](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#form-radiogroup), you'd have to add the `name` to each radiobutton. But for your use case, this configuration would be sufficient:

```
widget: {
          xtype: 'radio',
          simpleValue: true,
          name: 'test'
        }
```

See also [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/336u) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [checkcolumn](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Check.html) and change the records values that controls the check value using checkchange listener

Example:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkcolumn', 
    text: 'Active', 
    dataIndex: 'active',
    listeners: {
        checkchange: 'onChangeDefaultTopic'
    }
}
```

In your view controller:

```
onChangeDefaultTopic: function (column, rowIndex, checked, record) {
    if (checked) {
        store.getRange().forEach((rec) => {
            if (record.get('id') !== rec.get('id')) {
                rec.set('active', false)
            }

        });
    }
}
```